# How can I use maximum 10 chrome instance from 1 node and 1 port

Tags: selenium, grid

can I use maximum 10 chrome instance from 1 node same port (for selenium grid)
please help if there is any way?

Comment: You can create it using threads.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @user7309686 Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220159/how-many-maximum-number-of-simultaneous-chrome-connections-threads-i-can-start-t

Comment: after using max instance =10 and max session =10 , i am getting 10 browsers in grid ,but after increasing thread count to 42 still it uses 5 chrome at a time from that node. config shows 5 max session. please help